# How do I unify the output of a call predicate to save to another file

Tags: stream, prolog

I want to take the output of this code:

```
callfunction(X):-
    call(X).

append1([], L, L).
append1([X|Y], L2, [X|L3]):-
  append(Y, L2, L3).
```

and unify that with a another variable. 
For example: callfunction(append1([a,b],c,X)).
Gives me: X = [a,b|c].
I  want to use that output to print to a different stream. I imagine doing this by tying it to a variable. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
callfunction(X, ArgNum):-
    call(X), % Unificatioon happens
    arg(ArgNum,X,V), % Get's the (ArgNum)th argument. 
    tell('filename.txt'),writeln(V),told . % Write to finename.txt 

append1([], L, L).
append1([X|Y], L2, [X|L3]):-
  append(Y, L2, L3).
```

Calling it using `callfunction( append1([a,b],c,X), 3).`